# Scala Spark Handle Single Quote Characters With Commas

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I'm reading a CSV in Spark with scala and it handles line one correctly in the example below, but in line two of the example the line has an ending quote character, but no leading quote character for the first column.  This causes an issue by moving the data over and outputting `bad|col` in the final result, which is incorrect.

```
"good,col","good,col"
bad,col","good,col"
```

Is there an option to handle quote characters that don't have a leading (or ending) quote in the option specification when reading the file in spark with scala?

Answer (score 0):

Hm... by using rdd and with some replacements, I can obtain what you want.

```
val df = rdd.map(r => (r.replaceAll("\",\"", "|").replaceAll("\"", "").split("\\|"))).map{ case Array(a, b) => (a, b) }.toDF("col1", "col2")
df.show()

+--------+--------+
|    col1|    col2|
+--------+--------+
|good,col|good,col|
| bad,col|good,col|
+--------+--------+
```